# GPS service still running after using stopService()

Tags: java, android, service, gps, google-api-client

My application got a background service that handles location updates at a certain interval of time. I'm trying to stop the service to start a new one with a different interval but what ends up happening is that the application sends up two location updates at different intervals. Basically, my first service doesn't stop after using stopService().

Here's the code that starts the service:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_activity_f);

        tiempoGPS = 25000;
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ServicioDeFondo.class).putExtra("TiempoGPS", Integer.toString(tiempoGPS)));

    }
```

Here's the part where I stop it after clicking a button:

```
 private void selectItem(int position) {

...

        if(menus[position].equals("Configuracion"))
        {
            try {

                stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),ServicioDeFondo.class));

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                ...
            }
        }

}
```

Here my Service class onCreate method:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telefonoID = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        telephonyManager = null;

        createLocationRequest();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

OnstartCommand method:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
     {
         tiempoEntreActualizacion = Integer.parseInt((String)  intent.getExtras().get("TiempoGPS"));

        reportarGPS = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(tiempoEntreActualizacion);
                        new APISendClass().execute();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
         catch (Exception e)
        {
            //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } });

        reportarGPS.start();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Here's my service class onDestroy method:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy(){
    reportarGPS.interrupt();
    reportarGPS = null;
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    mGoogleApiClient = null;
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And last but not least, the methods where I start the locationUpdates:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            latitude =String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            longitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        }
        startLocationUpdates();
    }


    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
```

Been on stuck on this for 2 days now. I'm sure its some very basic mistake but I just can't point it out, my onDestroy method is been called but even after running it, the location is still being updated. Why?? How do I completely kill the service?

Comment: Do you also restart it in `selectItem(int)`?

Comment: The Service is started on onCreate in the activity and its stopped after I click a button. Both methods are included in the question.

Comment: I start a new service on a different activity all together after selectItem(int). I want the service to be killed off completely before that.

Comment: Could it be that, for some reason, the service is started more than once? Say the device is rotated and `onCreate()` for the activity is called repeatedly.  Maybe you could check if `reportarGPS` is null before creating a new thread and starting it?

Answer (score -2):

Your thread is wrong.  Its never chaecking if its been interrupted. Interrupting a thread does not stop it, it sets a flag that can be checked by the thread itself to see if its done.  (For a variety of reasons, stopping a thread from anywhere but itself is a really bad idea).  Make your while loop in the thread check isInterrupted and return from its run function if true.

Comment: In my thread where I send data, I got theInterruptionException where I use return.

Where exactly would I need to add the flag for the interruption?

Comment: `Thread.sleep(...)` throws `InterruptedException` if the thread is interrupted while it's sleeping, or was already interrupted when it was called.